# German word for "climbing move"

Tags: english-to-german

I was just watching the climbing world cup and wanted to say "amazing move" or something to that effect in German.

Google Translate gives "Kletterbewegung" for "climbing move", but that sounds very wrong and much too literal to me. In chess you would say "Zug", but does this transfer to other sports in German?

Comment: Für mich als Muttersprachler hat "Kletterbewegung" nichts an sich, das gegen die Verwendung spräche. Zug ist natürlich kürzer, aber ich bin nicht im Klettersport und weiß daher nicht, ob der Ausdruck nicht Bewegungen vorbehalten ist, die eine Ziehbewegung beinhalten, wobei die Bewegung ja womöglich eine Ziehbewegung beinhaltet hat. Dennoch würde natürlich interessieren, ob wie beim Schachzug, wo die Figur ja auch oft geschoben wird, das Wort Zug vielleicht allgemein verwendet wird.

Comment: Also ich denke bei *Kletterbewegung* spontan an eine große Gruppe Leute, die gerne klettern und andere überreden, sich ihnen anzuschließen - so im Sinne von "die Kletterbewegung gewinnt immer mehr Anhänger".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wikipedia gives you a list of [German climbing terms](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_der_Kletterbegriffe). As you thought there is the word Zug in it

> Zug: Bewegungssequenz, die notwendig ist, um beim Klettern den nächsten Griff zu erreichen.

English wikipedia has its own page for [climbing terms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_climbing_terms#M), which says

> Move: Application of a specific climbing technique to progress on a climb.

I think they are similar enough to translate move as Zug.

So you can say

> Netter Zug.
>
> Toller Zug.

etc.

But, to be honest, that sounds awkward for me. I would use some [Denglish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denglisch) (German/English combination) and say

> Netter/toller/großartiger Move

Please note: Denglish is often used in "Fun-Sports", when you want to sound hip & young, when there are no German terms at all or the English terms are the dominant ones.

Comment: Where I use to climb, _Zug_ absolutely doesn't sound awkward in this context, and is indeed the right term, while _Move_ would sound kind of strange (although it would be understood, but in a more general sense than _Zug_). Also, rock climbing isn't really a newly imported fun sport; historically, it developed in the Alps during the last 200 years, so there's enough original German terminology (cf. "to abseil"). It just seems to be hyped and re-promoted from English-speaking circles, currently.

Answer (score 3):

I am not active in this trade (climbing) but what comes first to my mind is

> Kletterzug

Sounds very natural to me. Simply *Zug* would be a variation as long as the context is already clear.